# Safari Unexpected CSS Token: :

Tags: html, css, filter, safari

I'm working on an application and it seems to be running fine in all browsers with exception to safari(Including the latest version)

It seems to be revolving around CSS lines such as the following.

```
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

The error simply states

```
Unexpected CSS token: :
```

Comment: That should not have any negative impact since browsers ignore invalid rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari is flagging the second `:` as invalid syntax.
You don't need to remove it, as browsers simply ignore invalid properties.

However, if for some reason you need it to be valid, or it's just bugging you, here's your options:

The easiest option is to just remove the `filter` property. You do lose IE8 support, which you may or may not need.

If you do need IE 8 support, use the `-ms-filter` attribute, and wrap the value in quotes:

```
-ms-filter: 'filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);';
```

You will now lose support for IE7 and below, as it is [only supported in IE8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx). However, since IE 7 makes up only [0.061% of the global browser usage](http://caniuse.com/usage-table), I wouldn't worry about that. Many/most/if not all websites don't actively support it anymore.

**Resources:**

[FontAwesome had an issue with this](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5043)